# How can a make a wait command in VB without using sleep command?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to find a type of wait command in VB Forms, but I do not want the sleep command because it freezes the program before it does all of the code. Is there any way to do this?

```
TextBox1.Text = "0"
' (Code goes here)
TextBox2.Text = "0"
```

Comment: What's the purpose of a "wait" in this code scenario?

Comment: Please stop tag spamming. VB.Net <> VBA <> VBScript. They're totally different languages. They're not the same just because they all start with *vb*, any more than a cat and a car and a carrot are all the same because they start with *ca*. Tags have meaning and relevance here. Please use only the ones that actually apply to your question.

Comment: The "wait" command in this scenario is to do a certain pause time (like a second) before continuing to the next line of code.

Comment: If you're using .NET 4.5 or above, mark the method that has this code as `Async` and then use `Await Task.Delay(1000)` for a non-blocking one second delay. Read [this Stephen Cleary's blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) for more about Async/Await.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Please re-write that as an answer because that logically is an answer.

Comment: There's no such thing as VB Forms. There is Windows Forms. Is that what you're using?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, it's Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer for this is to use `Async`/`Await` and a `Task.Delay`.

Just do this:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = "Immediately"
    Await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
    TextBox1.Text = "Later"
End Sub
```

Notice that I had to change the standard `Private Sub Button1_Click` handler signature to `Private Async Sub Button1_Click`.

The other option is to use a Windows Forms Timer. Just drag one from the toolbox onto your form.

Then you can do this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = "Immediately"
    Timer1.Interval = 2000
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    TextBox1.Text = "Later"
End Sub
```

If you want to stop the timer before it updates the text, you can do this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    TextBox1.Text = "Stopped"
End Sub
```